# Site automatically changing links to https

Tags: iis, https

I am having few issue with improper URL redirection.
My site is a MVC https site and I have few footer links which are supposed to be http.
In the layout file, I set the URL to www.example.net but when I click the link, it tries to browse as hhttps://www.example.net. If I add hhttp://www.example.net then it tries to browse as hhttps://http//www.example.net

So, can anyone please suggest if any links in the https site should be https as well? When I debug the code and it doesn't have https settings, the URL redirection works fine but only when I put it in server with https, this issues comes.

Note: I added a extra h infront of http or https to fix the no url rule.

Comment: try adding http:// instead of hhttp://

Comment: or if its a secure site https:// rather than hhttps://

Comment: I added that extra h just to bypass the stackoverflow no URL rule.
Thats why I added it as a note.

Comment: Is www.example.net supposed to be your site, or is that some external site? Why does it need to be under http, isn't it fine to leave it as https? What happens if you go to the URL directly instead of clicking the link in the footer? Does the same thing happen? Do you have an http to https redirect rule or anything in web.config or in global.asax?